# JAR or Maven dependency for wicketstuff-dojo

Tags: java, wicket

I want to use org.wicketstuff.dojo.markup.html.form.DojoDatePicker an so I am searching over internet for maven dependency of wicketstuff-dojo. From [MVN BROWSER](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifact-details.html?groupId=org.wicketstuff&artifactId=wicketstuff-dojo&version=1.3.0-beta&tab=FILES#tabs) I found a dependency. But It is not working I am getting "Missing artifact" error. If anybody knows the dependency or location from where I can download the JAR it will be very helpful to me.

My pom.xml is:

```
<dependencies>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-beta-9</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jdom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xom</groupId>
                <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.acegisecurity</groupId>
        <artifactId>acegi-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-remoting</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>gnujaxp</groupId>
                <artifactId>gnujaxp</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-spec-jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1B-rc4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>logkit</groupId>
                <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-lucene</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jca</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
                <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-guice</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-jmx</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-auth-roles</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxp-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2_1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1-final-20040804</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tmate</groupId>
        <artifactId>javasvn</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.ethz.ganymed</groupId>
                <artifactId>ganymed-ssh2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>casclient</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicketstuff-dojo</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>               
--></dependencies>
```

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's in it's [own repository](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/repositories.html#WICKET).
You'll have to add a `<repositories>` section in your `pom.xml`.