# Where to download wicketstuff-dojo binaries?

Tags: java, dojo, wicket, wicketstuff

I'm looking for wicketstuff-dojo binaries - legacy maven-based project depends on it.

I can't find it in maven repo - http://wicketstuff.org/maven/repository/
and I can't build it since it's missing some sh script in trunk.

Is there any place to get it? Or just by chance - do you have org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-dojo:jar:1.3.0-beta ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check this repo first: https://github.com/vijaykiran/wicketstuff-dojo

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963420/jar-or-maven-dependency-for-wicketstuff-dojo), but I'm not convinced the answer is complete.

Comment: I had to check out the wicketstuff-import-backup, then check out the right branch/tag.